# opengl32.lib wont link to project

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I've been building an OpenGL project and have tested it plenty of times, but for some reason now, I get this error:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'opengl32.lib'

I have no idea what happened. For some reason, it all of a sudden can't link them.

Any suggestions as to what may have caused this error out of nowhere?

Comment: Are you building your software for Windows RT by any chance? As ridiculous as it sounds, that platform supports GDI, DX but not GL.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Where would I be able to check?

Comment: You would generally know if you were writing software for Windows RT. It's an ARM-based platform for Microsoft's tablets. Unless you downloaded the wrong version of Visual Studio or selected the wrong build target you should be targeting Win32/x64 by default.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm targeting win32. My project was working fine until an hour ago after I removed a few libraries such as FreeImage and Assimp.

Comment: Did you also remove library search paths, by accident?

Comment: @user1781290 I think that's what I did. I just created a completely new project and now everything is working.